# Erro conceitual sobre funções em C++!

Tags: c++, c++11

bom dia!

Sou programador iniciante em C++, e certamente estou cometendo um erro conceitual ao criar funções, que não consegui detectar em nenhum fórum e material sobre C++. Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <cmath>

const int k = 3;
const int J = 6;
const int Q = 3;
constexpr size_t mdimenK = k;

double chi(const std::array<std::array<double,J>,mdimenK> &mB, const std::array<std::array<int,Q>,2> &qc, const std::array<long double, J> &sp); 

int main()
{
    std::array<std::array<double, J>,mdimenK> B{{
    {0.622, 0.168, 0.064, 0.070, 0.070, 0.005},
    {0.252, 0.489, 0.148, 0.039, 0.011, 0.061},
    {0.131, 0.368, 0.356, 0.088, 0.014, 0.043}
  }};

  std::array<std::array<int, Q>,2> qc{{
    {0,0,1},
    {1,2,2}
  }};

  std::array<long double, J> sp{2.1414738, 0.3732512, 0.1804191, 1.9928826, 0.2322304, 1.0797428};

  double chiold, chiest;

  chiold = chi(B, qc, sp); 

  chiest = chi(B, qc, sp);

  std::cout << "O valor de chiold é: " << chiold << " e de chiest é: " << chiest << std::endl;

  return 0;
}

double chi(const std::array<std::array<double,J>,mdimenK> &mB, const std::array<std::array<int,Q>,2> &qc, const std::array<long double, J> &sp) 
{
  std::array<std::array<double,J>,Q> dchi;
  std::array<double,Q> sChi;
  double sqrtChi;

  for(int q=0;q<Q;q++){
    for(int j=0;j<J;j++){
      dchi[q][j] = (pow((mB[qc[0][q]][j] - mB[qc[1][q]][j]),2)/sp[j]);
    }
  }

  for(int q=0;q<Q;q++){
    sChi[q] = 0;
    for(int j=0;j<J;j++){
      sChi[q] += dchi[q][j];
    }
  }

  for(int q=0;q<Q;q++){
    sqrtChi += sqrt(sChi[q]);
  }
  return sqrtChi;
}
```

Os valores de chiold e chiest era para ser o mesmo. No entanto, para minha surpresa e como sou iniciante nesta linguagem, os valores são diferentes. Alguém poderia me explicar qual é o erro conceitual? Já li sobre ponteiros, referência e etc, mas mesmo assim não consegui detectar o erro. Sou programador avançado na linguagem R.
Desde já agradeço por qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Poderia explicar o que o código deveria estar fazendo?

Comment: Use `using std`.

Comment: Parabéns porque percebe-se que mesmo iniciante entende o que está fazendo melhor que muito iniciante e alguns "experientes" (só acho feio esse monte de linha em branco e falta de espaços onde deixa mais legível), produziu um código C++ quase verdadeiro (só falhou no uso de `pow()` de C quando poderia ser de C++), mas também acho que falta nos dar subsídios para ajudá-lo. E quem sabe nem seja um erro de programação.

Comment: O ideal é explicar o seu código para que seja fácil as pessoas perceberem os valores obtidos e porque motivo o `chiold` e `chiest` deveriam ser iguais. A explicação deve ser ao nível do algoritmo utilizado e o que representam os valores finais obtidos.

Comment: Prezados, boa tarde. Desde já, agradeço a todos os comentários. Este trecho de código faz parte de um código bem mais complexo, em que, o objetivo é fazer um "simulated annealing", cujo o objetivo é minimizar/maximizar uma função **chi** de acordo com a matriz **B**, que vai se modificando ao longo de um "loop".  A função **chi** é responsável por computar a distância qui-quadrado. A matriz **B**, vai se alterando ao longo do "loop" de acordo com a matriz **Tn** (que não está no código).

Comment: Parte 2: Como a matriz **Tn** é uma matriz identidade na primeira iteração, então, o **chiold** e **chiest** devem ser iguais. Nos demais "loops", obviamente que estas variáveis vão se alterando. Como sou iniciante nesta linguagem, o meu "medo", é de estar com algum conceito errado, e assim, todo os cálculos de outras funções estiverem erradas. Logo, preciso entender como o C++ "pensa", para não cometer um erro grave. Aceito sugestões de livros entre outros materiais. Muito obrigado a todos. Fico no aguado.

Comment: Essas informações deve constar na pergunta e não como comentários. Edite-a e insira essas informações.

Answer (score 1):

o problema esta nessa linha:

```
double sqrtChi;
```

o correto seria :

```
double sqrtChi = 0;
```

caso vc nao instancie objeto a segunda chamada a sua funcao vai reutilizar o primeiro valor adicionado.

---

Uma segunda opcao 'e trocar `+=` por `=+` pq o =+ vai reescrever o primeiro valor com a segunda operacao da funcao, no caso do += vai usar o valor anterior da memoria mas o proximo valor da funcao.

Comment: Olá Hudson. De fato resolve o problema. No entanto, estou na busca do "porque", dado que o código é bem mais complexo do que exposto neste post. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Mais o objeto está dentro da função. Logo, eu imagino que cada vez que ela for chamada, o objeto dentro dela deveria ser reinicializado não:  Se  assim o for, então eu devo instanciar para zero os objetos dchi e schi correto? Essa é minha grande dúvida. Todo objeto criado dentro de uma função deve ser instanciado para zero, evitando o risco de tal objeto ser utilizado mais a frente caso a função seja chamada novamente?

Comment: @IvanBezerraAllaman caso vc usei `+=`  mas para frente sim vc precisa instaciar o objeto com um valor

Comment: editei adicionando uma segunda opcao com o operador `=+`, mas o melhor seria instanciar o objeto, para que o objeto na memoria sempre comece com o valor definido.

Comment: Valeu Hudson pelos esclarecimentos. Grande abraço.

Comment: ps. não existe "operador =+"...se você escreve "a =+ b" o significado é "a = (+b)", que é a mesma coisa que "a = b"

Comment: para inicializar com zeros os arrays dchi e schi na declaração a sintaxe é "std::array<...> dchi = {}"...veja   [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295302/default-initialization-of-stdarray) no SOen